# Flex 4.6 color style conflict between DropDownList and DataGroup

Tags: css, apache-flex

I am working on a flex application.  The project has a global style sheet with the declaration:

```
s|DataGroup{
    alternating-item-colors:#FFFFFF,#F7F7FA;
}
```

Now, in one of my dialogs, I want to have a DropDownList with a different color scheme.  I tried a number of things, using attributes and using a style for my DropDownList.

```
<s:DropDownList id="orientationEntry" width="200"
                dataProvider="{model.orientationList}"
                styleName="blackDropDown"
                alternatingItemColors="[#222222,#111111]"
                >
```

And in my style sheet (I tried a number of different things):

```
.blackDropDown s|DataGroup {
    alternating-item-colors: #222222,#111111;
}

#orientationEntry s|DataGroup {
    alternating-item-colors: #222222,#111111;
}

s|DropDownList#orientationEntry s|DataGroup {
    alternating-item-colors: #222222,#111111;
}
```

But none of these have any effect.  My dropdown list always shows white and light gray lines.  To make it work, (i.e. have black and dark gray lines), I need to remove the `s|DataGroup` declaration from the global stylesheet.  But I'd like to avoid that.  I am a bit surprised that a general declaration cannot be overridden for a more specific case.

So the question is: how can I override the background color of the popup list of my DropDownList without redefining the default colors of all datagroups of my application?

Or alternatively, how can I cancel the global `s|DataGroup` declaration without changing the global style sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can set this via as3, but if you want this reusable a way is:

Create a new MXML Skin based on DropDownList.

Search for (**CTRL+O** in some editor, write *scroller* and press ENTER or click to go):

```
<s:Scroller id="scroller" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" hasFocusableChildren="false" minViewportInset="1">
                <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableDataContainer#dataGroup-->
                <s:DataGroup id="dataGroup" itemRenderer="spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="contentJustify" requestedMinRowCount="1" requestedMaxRowCount="6"/>
                    </s:layout>
                </s:DataGroup> 
            </s:Scroller>
```

Set the attribute specifying your colors:

```
alternatingItemColors="{[0x222222, 0x111111]}"
```

You have now this:

```
<!--- @private -->
            <s:Scroller id="scroller" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" hasFocusableChildren="false" minViewportInset="1">
                <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableDataContainer#dataGroup-->
                <s:DataGroup id="dataGroup" alternatingItemColors="{[0x222222, 0x111111]}" itemRenderer="spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="contentJustify" requestedMinRowCount="1" requestedMaxRowCount="6"/>
                    </s:layout>
                </s:DataGroup> 
            </s:Scroller>
```

Now just set the skinClass in your component (my example is in the pacakage ***skins***):

```
<s:DropDownList id="ddlFiltros" width="237" height="30" buttonMode="true"

skinClass="skins.skin_dropdown"

dataProvider="{_arrayCamposFiltro}" labelField="label"
prompt="ELEGIR CAMPO" selectedIndex="-1"/>
```

And this is not affected for the global style.

However you can set this in your style:

```
s|DataGroup{
    alternating-item-colors:#FFFFFF,#F7F7FA;
}

.blackDropDown {
    skinClass: ClassReference("skins.skin_dropdown");
}
```

And instead of define skinClass, define styleName:

```
<s:DropDownList id="ddlFiltros" width="237" height="30" buttonMode="true" 

styleName="blackDropDown"

dataProvider="{_arrayCamposFiltro}" labelField="label"
prompt="ELEGIR CAMPO" selectedIndex="-1"/>
```

You get this:

[image]

Comment: I was afraid I would have to do that.  I am not so comfortable with it.  It seems to me that copying a whole skin just to set an attribute is overkill.  But on the other side, I actually see this a lot.  And it looks simple enough.  So if nobody comes up with a CSS solution, I will try that on Monday.

Comment: Flex 4.6 About inheritance in CSS - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62883-7ff2.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62883-7ff0

Comment: I think you can extend DropDownList and modify the alternating-item-colors

Comment: DropDownList already has an alternating-item-colors attribute, but nothing I have tried so far takes priority over the DataGroup attribute in the style sheet.  I would probably have to find the popup with the dataGroup in DropDownList, see when it is created and set the style at that time.

Comment: You can try setStyle o styleName in as3 accesing myDropDownList.dataGroup

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be a CSS-only solution, I implemented the Skin solution and accepted your answer.  It looks like it's the way to go after all.